# Need to change prototype of existing c function

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I need to call an existing C function from my Java code through JNI. As suggested by JNI I have created a header file for native C function using Javah tool then included same in C file.

Do i need to change function prototype for existing C function (as generated in header file)?

Please correct me if my sample code has any mistake

Sample Code:

```
         #include <stdio.h>
         #include <jni.h>
         #include "myHeader.h"
         int main(){
int result=Nativecall();
return 0;
 }
int NativeCall(){  //Native Method implementation
int sample=10;
return sample;
 }
  _______________
   myHeader.h

   JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_test__NativeCall
     (JNIEnv *, jobject);
```

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you are having? Or ... have you not simply tried your code to see if it works?

Comment: JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test_HelloWorld_print
  (JNIEnv *, jobject); this is the prototype for my c function in headerfile. Do i need to specify same protype to original functon defined in C file

Comment: You need to read up in what JNI is actually for and what it actually does. Your question betrays too many misconceptions to be addressed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't have to do anything, javah does the job for you,simply include the header file in your C file and implement the functions defined inside header file.
So According to your situation it should be like this,You can see that we are using same prototype as javah has defined in header file

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
    Java_test__NativeCall
                    (JNIEnv *env, 
                    jobject callingObject)
    {
    int sample=10;
    return (jint)sample;
    }
```

Comment: @krish131 if you have any code you wish to share, include it in question please.

Comment: @alex I have edited my query with sample code ..please correct me if my code has anything wrong

Comment: I have edited the answer :).Hope it helps